# How do you output an attribute using Perl and XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, hash

```
sub parse_xml{
    my $xml_link = $_[0];
    my $xml_content = get($xml_link) or warn "Cant get XML page of " . $xml_link . "\n";
    if(!$xml_content){
        return;
    }
    my $xml =  XML::Simple->new(KeepRoot => 1);
    my $xml_data = $xml->XMLin($xml_content);
    my @items = $xml_data->{rss}{channel}->{item};
   # print Dumper($xml_data);
    foreach my $item (@items) {
        if($item){
             print Dumper($item);             //This is the dump output
             print $item->{author};
             #print $item . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to output the item's author I just get either `HASH(Memory Address)` or `not a hash reference at ... line ...`

Am I doing this incorrectly? Why is it producing this error?

Here is the dumper output.

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'link' => 'http://***.com/article/news/betty-white-credits-snickers-golden-opportunities/144290/#comments-67229',
            'author' => {},
            'title' => 'By: ',
            'pubDate' => 'Tue, 08 Jun 2010 12:47 EDT',
            'description' => 'Interesting. At least SHE remembered the product that propelled her to recent recognition. When many people I know have commented on how they loved that Betty White Super Bowl spot, they can&#039;t recall the product. Ah, advertising.'
          },
          {
            'link' => 'http://***.com/article/news/betty-white-credits-snickers-golden-opportunities/144290/#comments-67167',
            'author' => {},
            'title' => 'By: ',
            'pubDate' => 'Mon, 07 Jun 2010 13:26 EDT',
            'description' => 'Fun, fun, fun. A great attitude for all of us to take into our careers.'
          },
          {
            'link' => 'http://****.com/article/news/betty-white-credits-snickers-golden-opportunities/144290/#comments-67164',
            'author' => 'username',
            'title' => 'By: username',
            'pubDate' => 'Mon, 07 Jun 2010 12:23 EDT',
            'description' => 'Her appearance of the Comedy Central roast of William Shattner a couple of years ago was great... it seems like her willingness to be irreverent makes her more appealing to us all!  

www.adverspew.com'
          },
          {
            'link' => 'http://****.com/article/news/betty-white-credits-snickers-golden-opportunities/144290/#comments-67142',
            'author' => {},
            'title' => 'By: ',
            'pubDate' => 'Mon, 07 Jun 2010 09:50 EDT',
            'description' => 'Solid interview. I will definitely be tuning into &quot;Hot in Cleveland&quot; next week. We ought to enjoy Ms. White&#039;s talents for as long as we have her. She&#039;s great!'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to answer if you printed the output from `Dumper($item->{author})` - matter of fact, doing so might tell you what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: Since the answer didn't state this outright - any time when you print the expression's value in Perl and you get `HASH(address)`, it means that whatever you had was a hashref.

Comment: [XML::Feed](http://p3rl.org/XML::Feed) exists, no need to write this custom parser.

Comment: Probably want to use the SuppressEmpty option

Answer (score 1):

You're very much on the right track. I've used your code on the newsfeed linked from this StackOverflow page, and adapted it very slightly.

```
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
sub parse_xml{
    my $xml_link = $_[0];
    my $xml_content = get($xml_link) or warn "Cant get XML page of " . $xml_link . "\n";
    if(!$xml_content){
        return;
    }
    my $xml =  XML::Simple->new(KeepRoot => 1);
    my $xml_data = $xml->XMLin($xml_content,ForceArray =>'entry');
    foreach my $item ($xml_data->{'feed'}[0]->{'entry'}) {
        foreach my $entry (@{$item}){
            if($entry){
                print $entry->{'author'}[0]->{'name'}[0]."\n";
                print $entry->{'author'}[0]->{'uri'}[0]."\n";
            }
        }

    }

}
parse_xml('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10906521');
```

Works fine on that example. I suspect that you might be trying to print out something that isn't a plain value  -- in the example of the stackoverflow page, you can see that the 'author' actually contains some child nodes, so that if you try printing $item->{'author'} in the foreach loop you will get the 'HASH' result you describe.

Looking at your dump and Borodin's wise comment, this ought to work for you:

```
   my $xml_data = $xml->XMLin($xml_content,ForceArray =>'entry');
    my $item = $xml_data->{'rss'}[0]->{'channel'}[0]->{'item'};
    foreach my $entry (@{$item}){
        if($entry){
            if(!ref $entry->{'author'}[0]){
                    print $entry->{'author'}[0]."\n";
            }
            if(!ref $entry->{'description'}[0]){
                    print $entry->{'description'}[0]."\n";
            }
            if(!ref $entry->{'pubDate'}[0]){
                    print $entry->{'pubDate'}[0]."\n";
            } # etc.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This RSS feed may or may not have `<author>` information for each item.

If there is no author then the element still appears in the XML but it has no content. It appears as `<author></author>`.

`XML::Simple` will represent this as an empty anonymous hash.

So, if there is author information for an item, `$item->{author}` will be a simple text string. Otherwise it will be a hash reference.

You can code for this by writing

```
foreach my $item (@items) {
  my $author = $item->{author};
  $author = '' if ref $author;
  print "$item\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I solved this by checking if $item was a hash table.  It seems that it was inconsistent, sometimes returning a hash, sometimes not.

Comment: @user979663: I cannot see how `$item` can ever be anything other than a hash reference. Do you mean checking `$item->{author}`? This will be either a string or a hash refence. My code checks to see if it is a hash reference by using `if ref $author`.